# How to determine the RLC values for a bandstop filter

Tags: passive-networks, fourier, band-pass

I've been looking through the vague online documentation for designing a basic bandstop filter. I have the two frequencies which I want to attenuate but I cant seem to find how to calculate the values for the RLC circuit. From what I have gathered, it will be a parallel circuit of two individual filters and I calculate L and C by using the formula f = 1/2π√LC.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe start by looking at low and high pass filters. Notice how the attenuation of either depends on frequency; there is no single frequency the filter responds to. Find out how much you need to attenuate the signal at the desired frequency, and how much attenuation of other frequencies in the range you can accept. This will give you a clue as to which _order_ of a filter you may require. A band pass filter is just a high pass filter in series with a low pass filter, where the high pass filter is tuned for the a lower frequency than the low pass.

Comment: As the band pass can be imagined as passing certain a signal and not passing others, you connect the output of the band pass filter to ground which basically short circuits the signal of the specific frequency range to ground while leaving the other signal components intact.

Comment: Your question is vague also. You need to talk real numbers here so that the microwave guys know it's not an audio application and the other analogue guys know what input and output impedances are involved, what signal levels you are using and what power supplies are available.

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough sketch about how you can do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9k6TB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

HP1 and HP2 are the high pass filters for frequency 1 and 2, respectively.

LP1 and LP2 are the low pass filters for frequency 1 and 2, respectively.

F(HP1) < f1 < F(LP1)

F(HP2) < f2 < F(LP2)

I.e., the cutoff frequencies of the HPs and LPs should be below and above your specific frequencies f1 and f2.

Comment: Thank you so much @JimmyB, will run through this tomorrow and see what I can figure out.